# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect configuration for selfhosted Auth0 server

Tags: asp.net, openid-connect

There is a self hosted Oauth2.0 OpenIdConnect server: https://id.yyy.com/

I try to configure OpenIdConnect using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect`:

```
 {
     opt.ClientId = "CLIENT_ID";
     opt.ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
     opt.Authority = "https://id.xyz.com";
     opt.ResponseType = "code";
     opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
     opt.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Auth/Callback");

     var cfg = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration();
     cfg.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://id.xyz.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth2/authorize";
     cfg.UserInfoEndpoint = "https://id.xyz.com/accounts/profile/";
     cfg.TokenEndpoint = "https://id.xyz.com/oauth2/token/";
     opt.Configuration = cfg;
 });
```

the resulting request looks like this:
`https://id.yyy.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth2/authorize&client_id=CLIENT_ID%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:5000%2FAuth%2FCallback%26response_type=code&scope=openid&profile:read`,
so the authorisingEndpoint is `https://id.yyy.com/accounts/login/?next=/oauth2/authorize` so i need to use `/?next=/oauth2/authorize?` instead of `/?next=/oauth2/authorize&` after this endpoint. Is it possible to configure this behavior? Or have I a mistake in my configuration?